# How can i insert into MSSQL text Datatype field as xml

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

How can i insert into TSQL text field containing xml.

I can create custom fields in one of my Application which uses MSSQL as a back-end. When i create those custom fields, all go to a single field called `fldxml` in a table called `MIITEM`. I want to write Insert and update statement but i don't know how to insert record into `fldxml` field between `<field></field>`

```
<field1></field1>   is custFld1( Custom Field1)
<field2></field2>   is custFld2( Custom Field2)
<field3></field3>   is custFld3( Custom Field3)
<field4></field4>   is custFld4( Custom Field4)
```

here is how the data looks like in the field

```
<fields><field3>PFB652S6</field3><field1></field1><field2></field2><field4></field4></fields>
```

[image]

here is the Data Type

[image]

Comment: Don't use the text datatype. It has been deprecated in favor of varchar(max) for over a decade. The text datatype is incredibly difficult to work with. For the question at hand I don't understand what you are trying to do and the sample "xml" you posted is not valid xml.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed you should not use the TEXT datatype. For this purpose, use XML instead.

Regardless of the datatype, you can modify XML in TSQL by using the TSQL XML DML functionality. This makes it possible to write DML statements like INSERT, MODIFY, DELETE to modify XML documents.

Below is an example demonstrating this on your document:

```
-- First declare a variable of type XML
DECLARE @fields xml;

-- Here are the values we will be manipulating
DECLARE @nodeToReplace VARCHAR(MAX),@newValue VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @nodeToReplace = 'field3'
SET @newValue = 'PFB652S6'

-- Then fetch the value from the database. Insert the correct where clause
SELECT @fields=CAST(fldxml AS XML) FROM MIITEM WHERE .....

-- Now @fieds will contain your XML
SELECT @fields AS OldValue;  

-- When the value of the node is empty, you have to insert the text node as follows.
SET @fields.modify('  
  insert text {sql:variable("@newValue")} as last into (/fields/*[ local-name()=sql:variable("@nodeToReplace") ])[1]
');  
SELECT @fields AS NewInsertedValue;  

-- When the value is present already, a slightly different syntax must be used to update it
SET @newValue = 'BLABLA'
SET @fields.modify('  
  replace value of (/fields/*[local-name()=sql:variable("@nodeToReplace")][1]/text())[1]  
  with     sql:variable("@newValue")
');  
SELECT @fields AS NewUpdatedValue;
```

Feel free to let me know if this sufficiently answers your questions. I could provide more specific help if needed.